# Overriding variable in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have this in my puppet fle for solr:

```
define solr::core(
$solr_home = "/opt/solr",
$schema_xml = "searchapi_schema.xml",
$solrconfig_xml = "searchapi_solrconfig.xml",
$user = 'jetty'
) { ..
```

I would like to in my node override the variables for $schema_xml and $solrconfig_xml, how do I do that in a nice way?

I tried this:

```
node web02 inherits webbasenode {
  $schema_xml = "apachesolr_schema.xml"
  $solrconfig_xml = "apachesolr_solrconfig.xml"
...
```

But that did not work out.

Comment: When you say it did not work it's helpful to explain exactly what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the variables when you instantiate the resource:

```
node 'web02' {
  solr::core { 'myservername':
    schema_xml     => 'apachesolr_schema.xml',
    solrconfig_xml => 'searchapi_solrconfig.xml',
  }
}
```

Comment: Lovely! Worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use hiera you can do it like

In your manifest

```
$schema_xml = hiera ( 'schema_xml_h' , 'default_value' )
$solrconfig_xml = hiera ( 'solrconfig_xml_h', 'other_default_value')
```

and in hiera

```
$schema_xml: something
solrconfig_xml_h : something_else
```